# Как получить порядковый номер выделенного текста внутри конкретного элемента?

Tags: javascript, html, range

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('mouseup', '#text', function(e) {
    var selection = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    console.log(selection.toString());
    // ???
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="text">
  Lorem ispum Lorem ispum
  <span>Lorem ispum</span>
  <strong>Lorem ispum</strong> Lorem ispum
</div>
```

Собственно, как получить порядковый номер выделенного фрагмента внутри контейнера #text? Например, при выделении мышкой слова "ispum" внутри strong результатом должно быть число 4, по тому, что это четвертое от начала слово "ispum" внутри #text.

Comment: *Например, при выделении мышкой слова "ispum" внутри strong результатом должно быть число 4* - А почему 4?

Comment: По тому, что это четвертое от начала слово "ispum" внутри #text

Comment: Выделенного текста или слова?

Comment: Выделенного фрагмента. Т.е. можно выделить и "Lorem ispum", тогда необходимо вернуть какой по счету фрагмент выделен внутри #text.

Comment: А зачем вам это надо? Может, можно решить вашу реальную задачу. Почему-то мне кажется, что получение порядкого номера - не  конечная цель.

Comment: Именно конечная - нужно получить выделенный пользователем кусок текста в каком-то контейнере на странице, а если он в этом контейнере не один, то и его порядковый номер внутри контейнера для дальнейших манипуляций на сервере.

Comment: _при выделении мышкой слова "ispum" внутри strong результатом должно быть число 4_ - А почему `4`? ага, увидел предыдущие комментарии

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача весьма не тривиальная. Из-за разности представления пробельных символов браузером и их реального количества.

Если упростить задачу, установив значение свойства `white-space` в значение `pre`, то можно воспользоваться следующим подходом:

1. [selection.startOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/startOffset) покажет индекс начала выделения внутри элемента.
2. подняться до уровня контейнера `div#test` попутно вычисляя количество символов с начала элемента
3. взять [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) контейнера и получить нужную подстроку
4. произвести `split` по выбранному куску текста - количество элементов в получившемся массиве и будет искомым порядковым номером.

Пример реализации:

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('mouseup', '#text', function(e) {
    var selection = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    var index = selection.startOffset;
    el = selection.startContainer.previousSibling || selection.startContainer.parentNode;

    while (el.id != "text") {
      while (el.previousSibling) {
        el = el.previousSibling;
        index += el.textContent.length;
      }
      el = el.parentNode;
    }

    console.log(el.textContent.substring(0, index).split(selection.toString()).length);
  })
})
```

```css
#text {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="text">
  Lorem ispum Lorem ispum
  <span>Lorem ispum</span>
  <strong>Lorem ispum</strong> Lorem ispum
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для начала попробуем придумать как найти такой порядковый номер. Упростим задачу и допустим, что вложенных блоков нет. Тогда можно находить все вхождения выделенного текста до тех пор, пока его позиция будет меньше или равна левой границе выделения. Функция поиска может быть такой:

```
function findAndCount(text, search, limit) {
    var count = 0;
    var fromIndex = 0;
    var pos = text.indexOf(search, fromIndex);
    while (pos >= 0 && pos <= limit) {
        ++count;
        fromIndex = pos + search.length;
        pos = text.indexOf(search, fromIndex);
    };

    return count;
}
```

Следующая задача это придумать способ найти левую границу выделения для документа с вложенными блоками. `Range` имеет свойство `startContainer` -- элемент, с которого начинается диапазон. У элементов, кажется, нет свойства позиции в тексте, но можно попробовать заменить элемент уникальной последовательностью символов, и найти позицию этой последовательности в тексте родителя.

Уникальный текст можно сгенерить так:

```
function generateBoundary(text, tryLimit) {
    var boundary;
    var pos = 0;
    do {
        --tryLimit;
        boundary = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15); // лаконичное решение из интернета
        pos = text.indexOf(boundary);
    } while (pos >= 0 && tryLimit > 0);

    return boundary;
}
```

Позицию элемента так (я испольую jQuery):

```
function findElTextPosition($el, $parent) {
    var boundary = generateBoundary($parent.text(), 5);
    $el.replaceWith(boundary);
    var pos = $parent.text().indexOf(boundary);

    return pos;
}
```

Испытаем:

```
$(function() {
    var $mainEl = $('#text');
    $(document).on('mouseup', '#text', function(e) {
        var selection = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        var text = $mainEl.text();
        var selectedText = selection.toString();
        var offset = selection.startOffset;
        var childOffset = 0;
        if (selection.startContainer !== $mainEl[0]) { // если выделение во вложенном элементе
            childOffset = findElTextPosition($(selection.startContainer), $mainEl);
        }

        console.log(selectedText, findAndCount(text, selectedText, offset + childOffset));
    });
});
```

Способ конечно так себе, и если не клонировать элемент `#text`, то работает только один раз. Но можно допилить при желании.

P.S.
Вероятно нет причин использовать такой подход, если только вы не пишете что-то очень особенное.